# highlight content in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

i have following code for 2 files named try1 and try2.

1.try1.php

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 1000px">

    <iframe name="frametest" id="frameDemo" src="try2.php" style="height:     100%;width: 100%;z-index: 10"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

2.try2.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <pre>
                <?php echo       htmlentities(@file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com")); ?>
        </pre>    
    </div>

</body>
```

how can i highlight all the a href links in the iframe in try1.php ?
I think this could be done by jquery bt how ?

Answer (score 0):

On javascript itself, you could use this :)

```
var aElement = document.getElementById('frameDemo').contentWindow.getElementsByTagName("a");
```